# Runs in IDE but not on Server

Tags: php

I have a program which runs well on IDE and echo's successful with no errors.

But if the same program when run on a browser like firefox or chrome doesn't show up anything.

Its just a blank page.

Is there anything that i need to add in script to run on Browser or i am doing anything wrong?

Comment: You have to provide us more details.

Comment: What do you mean it runs well on IDE?  Do you mean you don't get any errors from your IDE or do you mean it runs fine from the command line?  Also you can turn on errors with   error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED); and
    ini_set("display_errors",1);

Comment: blank page = error , you should try enable them : error_reporting(-1);

Comment: Pedantic note: _browsers_ do not execute PHP files. PHP is typically interpreted by the webserver.

Comment: thank you all ..i did not have error reporting in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons your script could be choking when served from a webserver. ... You *do* have a webserver working properly and able to run other scripts, right?

Make sure error reporting and error handling is properly set up to display errors.
Add this snippet at the top of your script if you want a quick and dirty way of doing this.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

1. Check webserver is working ok with other script
2. Use a debugger, if you have one ...

2.a If you don't have a debugger, here is a quick poor-man-debugger's tutorial: add an `exit;`  in your script where you know it should output something, then use   a`var_dump` if necessary just before the exit to see if your expectations match the output.  Repeat with the next instruction, until you get to the point where the output in var_dump does not match what you expect.

On a friendly side-note, next time you post,  please give more details *or even a  code snippets or two* of relevant code.  This will bring you much more specific and relevant answers.